# Npm run deploy using GHpages overwrites the content I am trying to push to my website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Every time I update my files and use npm build and npm deploy, it just pulls from what's already there and overwrites the files I'm trying to send. I've tried changing the package config as well as installing NPM watch that was suggested on here. I have moved directories and edited it so that it would be coming from a different area.

Every time I npm build or deploy it completely overwrites what I'm trying to send, with what is already there. Any tips would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: What is you gh build script? You may be pushing another branch.